# is it a safe code from mysql injections?some suggestions please

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am developing a system for a client. I need some suggestions for that. Is this a safe code to prevent sql injection?

```
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=md5($_POST["password"]);

$num_rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from table where username='$username' AND password='$password'"));

if($num_rows>0)
{
    echo "Logged in";
}
else 
{
    echo "Incorrect username or password";
}
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.
Please elaborate your answer why the above code is unsafe.Thanks
please dont negative vote the question if you dont have any answer.

Comment: Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Comment: your script is open for SQL Injections do some validations before adding user inputs in MySQL query and `mysql` extension is deprecated use `mysqli` OR `PDO` (PHP Data Objects) ,

Comment: can you provide any sql injection which can satisfy this condition?

Comment: Check the duplicate link, and use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for password hashing. MD5 is old and considered broken.

Answer (score 2):

No, the code is unsafe for SQL Injection, especially `$username` variable. You should escape the variable, via `mysql_real_escape_string()`. If I were you, I will add `trim()` function to both user name and password, as users sometimes add spaces before / after text input accidentally.

More importantly, Stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use MySQLi / PDO instead.

Note: `$password` is fine, as it's generated by `md5()` hash, which won't contain any character that leads to SQL error / injection.

Comment: check my answer friend

Answer (score 0):

the upper code is not satisfying any of the sql injections like

```
' or '1'='1' -- 
' or '1'='1' ({ 
' or '1'='1' /*
```

how u can say that it is open for sql injections.can you elaborate your answers friends?

Comment: this is not an answer. Please use **edit** button in your question.

Comment: yes this is not an answer friend,but this is answer for those who r saying the above code is open for sql injection :)

Comment: sql injections are those queries which will always return some results from the database by satisfying the condition like $a='abc OR 1=1 '  username=$abc. as 1 is always equals to 1 so it will return some positive results.

Comment: bro i know wat is safe and unsafe,please read my question i m asking,how u can say the above code is unsafe,thats it.

Comment: I just put your code in a file and, aside from the fact that I had to change table to `table` in order to make it a valid query, the first line you have in your "answer" will log you in to any user perfectly fine. If you don't know what you're doing, I'd highly recommend using an authentication system someone else wrote rather than leaving huge security holes in your client's system. If this is a personal project, great, but please don't try to develop production code similar to this.

Comment: Ryan how can u login without having valid username and password in the above query and script?can u explain?